# Form select element is erratically cut off in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-select

I am seeing some strange behavior in Firefox in regards to form select fields.

Depending on viewport width, a select with, say, a width of `33.333%` will sometimes have its right borders cut off.

[image]

please see this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pjv0adhw/

What I have is a horizontally centered parent container with an absolute width, containing a select with a fractional width, like so:

```
.parent {
  margin: 0 auto; /* centered on viewports > 1200px */
  width: 300px;
}
.select {
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

Simplified markup:

```
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <select class="select">
      <option>cat</option>
      <option>dog</option>
      <option>manatee</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now, on Firefox, when the viewport width is wider than 300px and the `.parent` element is centered, the `select` starts behaving weirdly.

In even viewport widths (`302px`, `1326px`), all is well. But in odd viewport widths (`301px`, `1317px`), the select's right border is being cut off.

I've seen this in Firefox 32-35. Other browser vendors don't seem to be affected.

Also, this happens only when the `option`s are narrower than the `select`.

I'm guessing that what happens is that, if the left-over viewport width is an odd number, some calculations for the `margin: auto;` property are counting half-pixels and making rounding errors.

What I can't seem to grasp is how the margins on the parent can have any impact at all on its children, whose fractional width, as I understand it, should always be calculated based on the parent's absolute width of `300px`.

Am I missing something fundamental about the box model here, or is this simply a bug in Firefox? Is there a known workaround for this issue that I haven't dug up yet?

On a sidenote, `box-sizing: border-box;` does not seem to have any effect on this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o83dd7w5/)

This is easily solved using `flexbox`to resize your `select`s

here's a screen shot ran from firefox
[image: the border on the second select is not being cut anymore]

HTML

```
<div>
    <select class='flex-1'>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
    </select>
    <select class='flex-2'>
        <option>cat</option>
        <option>dog</option>
        <option>manatee</option>
    </select>
    <span class='flex-3'></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div{
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: slategray;
    display: flex;
}
[class*='flex']{
  flex-basis: 0;
}
.flex-1{ flex-grow: 1; }
.flex-2{ flex-grow: 2; }
.flex-3{ flex-grow: 3; }
```

more info about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

This issue [has been reported to firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924068), and there is a nice workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjv0adhw/10/

I have played around it a bit and this seems to be working with the code you provided. The thing is to set a sizing container and then make the section only 99.99% of its width. Something like this:

```
.sizing-container { width: *desiredwidth*; }
.sizing-container section { width: 99.99%; }
```

I also tried to implement this bit of browser-specific code:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

But somehow in your case this did not seem to solve the problem.

I hope it helped, Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.select {
  width: calc(100%/3);
}
```